# ¿Cómo puedo descargar un pull request de account_chart_update en local? Para odoo 9

Tags: git, odoo, openerp

En odoo 9, tengo instalada la localización española (l10n_es) y el módulo AEAT modelo 303, pero no me funciona correctamente porque necesito añadir el módulo de account_chart_update, que todavía no está migrado a odoo9. He visto que hay un pull request, que está operativo.

¿Cómo puedo descargar el contenido de este pull request?

La dirección del pull request es esta:

https://github.com/OCA/account-financial-tools/pull/420

Por supuesto, no soy propietario del proyecto de odoo ni de la pull request.

Según he visto en la documentación, hay que hacer esto:

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

Adaptado sería algo así:

```
git fetch origin pull/420/head:pr_local
```

¿Pero dónde le digo que descargue de la dirección del pull request?

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta está relacionada de algún modo con la **programación** informática? Por lo que veo, estás pidiendo instrucciones de uso de un programa, lo cual no está relacionado con este foro (a no ser que el programa sea una herramienta de compilación/programación como un IDE, compilador, middleware, etc.)

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es una pregunta sobre programación.

Comment: @SJuan76, no sé si el fallo está en la programación del módulo en el mal uso del mismo. De todos modos, he visto muchísimas preguntas en stackoverflow (en inglés) que no preguntan nada de programación, y la gente contesta igual. Cerrando la pregunta antes de contestarla no se soluciona nada.

Comment: Si hay una pregunta de programación, por favor pon el código que has probado/está dando problemas. Y que a veces se responda a preguntas que deberían ser cerradas no es un motivo para no cerrar las que se lo merezcan.

Comment: @SJuan76 ya está editada la pregunta para cumplir la normativa. Al final sí que era una pregunta de programación :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución:

Primero tenía que descargar la rama 9.0 de account_financial_tools:

```
git clone https://github.com/OCA/account-financial-tools.git -b 9.0
```

A continuación, descargar el pull request:

```
cd account-financial-tools
git fetch origin pull/420/head:pr_local
```

Y después cambiar a la nueva rama creada:

```
git checkout pr_local
```

Ahora sí, tengo accesible el código de todo el pull request